# Open a web browser in a PHP cli app

Tags: php

Disclaimer: I did not think through the right language to use for this project before I developed it. I should have used Python for the `webbrowser.open()` function knowing that I needed to open browsers. But anyways.. A shot in the dark.

I am working on a PHP command line application. I am almost done, and the last feature allows the user to open a browser using the command line, much like `redmine-cli`'s `redmine-cli open [issue #]` [command](https://github.com/yanjost/redmine-cli).

Checking the source, I can tell that Redmine CLI uses the [webbrowser.open](https://github.com/yanjost/redmine-cli/blob/master/redminecli/main.py#L111).. But I am using PHP [the worst language to make a CLI app out of?].

I knew they wouldn't work, but a shot at the dark, I tried to user the `header()` function in PHP, as well as embedding the `window.open()` JS.. Which, obviously doesn't work.

I want to open a web browser in my PHP cli app. Is it possible, or should I just rewrite the app [sigh] in Python?

Comment: *Off-topic:* Your username made my day.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I think you've said that to me before, to which I replied I liked your username too.

Comment: Have you tried `exec('xdg-open http://google.com');`? http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open

Comment: `exec` or `passthru` could work, though perhaps the PHP could output the URL and the user could pipe it to their browser, like: `firefox $(./command.php)`.

Comment: I love you guys!! I am on the Mac, so the command is `open`. I guess I'll add in some code to check if `xdg-open` exists, if-not, use `open`. Good resource: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144047/how-does-xdg-open-do-its-work

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ @cerebriform - how would I detect whether to use `xdg-open` (which is a Linux command) or `open` (a Mac command)? It seems it's a platform-specific command.

Comment: `which open` will resolve the file path if `open` is available, similarly `which xdg-open`.